# Aligning columns and associated data based on similar times/dates in excel

Tags: excel, date, time, match, similarity

I have two sets of data.

Dataset 1 has a time and date associated with a dive depth (column B). These times are (mostly) at 90s intervals.

Dataset 2 has a time and date associated with a seafloor depth (column E), but these times and dates are much less frequent and rarely match the dive depth time exactly.

I need each dive depth to be associated with a seafloor depth based on the time it was recorded.

For example in the table below, I would want all of the dive depths seen here to be associated with the value from E2 as this is the closest data temporally, and I would like this to be displayed in the column C.

Both sets of data cover a time period of over a month and I have many thousands of rows worth of dive data.

[image]

Comment: Does dataset 1 and dataset 2 have 'seconds' data? (I can only see hour and minute.)

Comment: Yes they do, I guess I left it out of the cell formatting

Comment: option 1 : You may share a sample file/data (with seconds data) for others to assist.. option 2: Or copy the data (with seconds) as text and paste it in the question like [this..](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314547/how-do-i-paste-an-excel-sheet-to-the-questions-on-stack-overflow/314550#314550)